# UIActivityViewController on iOS 8 show "more" button with custom activities

Tags: ios, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Now XCode 6 with iOS 8 SDK is out, we can talk about stuff.
I tried to use custom activities with UIActivityViewController on iOS 7, everything worked fine.
But on iOS 8, when custom activities are shown, there is "more" button sitting next to them and clicking on this button show exactly the same custom activities.
Did anyone find a workaround to remove this button? I couldn't find any solution yet.

[image: Redundant More button]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing to workaround. The "More..." button lets the user reorder the icons. This is now standard in iOS 8.

Comment: I've also noticed that the UIActivityViewController now adds the option for other apps to be included in the Share list via the More button - and I've tried some of these apps and decidedly do not want to allow sharing via the apps - is there any way to enable only system apps for sharing?